# In SQL Server 2012, what does it mean if I don't specify anything after "Return"?

Tags: sql-server

I am a beginner and trying to understand what we are doing there. I don't see anything after "RETURN" and is there a hidden ELSE that SETs the value?

```
SET @Context_Info = dbo.fnGetCustomerID(@CustomerGroup) 

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_requests WHERE context_info = @Context_Info AND session_id != @@SPID) 
BEGIN 
    RETURN 
END 
SET context_info @Context_Info

select * from customer;
select * from products;
```

Comment: Sets what value?

Comment: In that code sample it doesn't do anything because the code sample is invalid and will throw an error. But if it was valid.... RETURN jumps out of the script straight away. You normally only use it in stored procedures. You should post all of the script.

Comment: makes sense now...
it's a long 700 lines stored procedure and it works. I was trying to understand how it works statement by statement. thus didn't paste the entire thing

Answer (score 0):

There is no hidden else here, if the following `IF` condition returns true, the script cursor will return to the original caller.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_requests WHERE context_info = @Context_Info AND session_id != @@SPID)
```

If the `IF` condition returns false i.e. there are not records with the given `SELECT`, then only it will set the `context_info` to the assigned variable.

Treat the script like any `IF` conditional workflow in programming world.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL if you specify a RETURN somewhere in your code means, no code after that RETURN will be executed

So here it means if the condition in your If statement satisfies then nothing else below this won't execute.

If your requirement is to execute the last line if there are no rows matching the if statement :
The above can also be written like this

```
SET @Context_Info = dbo.fnGetCustomerID(@CustomerGroup) 
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_requests 
WHERE context_info = @Context_Info AND session_id != @@SPID) 
    BEGIN 
        SET context_info @Context_Info
    END
```

Comment: I tried using... below but last statement doesn't execute..

IF NOT EXISTS ( select * from HumanResources.Employee where JobTitle = 'Design Engineer')
BEGIN
 PRINT 'EXISTS executed'
 RETURN
END

select * from HumanResources.Shift where ShiftID=1;
select * from HumanResources.Shift where ShiftID=2;
select * from HumanResources.Shift where ShiftID=3;
PRINT 'NOT EXISTS executed'

Comment: Why are you using the return? what is the purpose?

Comment: it is part of a long stored procedure which replicates changes for a group which has lot of tables and I am trying to understand why they kept it with an empty return.

Comment: What I understand from yiu problem statement is that you don't need that return.